# in the iPhone App Store app, what's the control at the top of the featured view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it a Segmented Control?

About the featured view, is it purely a tableview? how could they make the Segmented Control to be permanent instead of scrolling with the table cells down below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Ertebolle says its a UISegmentedControl set as the titleView of the navigationItem.

You can also create elements within the view that don't scroll with the tableview by adding a UITableView as a subview of a UIViewController's view. Setting its frame property means that you can have a scrollable tableview in a fixed certain position in your view and other elements in the view that don't scroll with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it is a `UISegmentedControl`. But it's set as the title view of the navigation bar - to reproduce the whole effect, you'd create a `UINavigationController`, push a `UITableViewController` as the top view in it, and set the `titleView` of the table view controller's `navigationItem` to that segmented control. This would automatically anchor the toolbar / segmented control on top.